# find all occurrences of text in file on all branches

Tags: git

I removed a dependency from a Maven project, and I want to check that the lines were removed from all branches, local and remote.
How can I return all parent/pom.xml files from all branches, and grep them for "requestanalyzer"?

There are a hundred remote branches. After this operation I don't want to be left with 100 local branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git for-each-ref` can give you the list of all local and remote branches :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads refs/remotes/origin
```

`git grep` can find any pattern in any commit, with filters on file names :

```
git grep [pattern] [commit] -- [file pattern]

# in your case : look for '<artifactid>requestanalyser' in all pom.xml files :
git grep '<artifactId>requestanalyzer' some/branch -- **/pom.xml
```

---

You can combine these two commands, using for example a bash loop :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads refs/remotes/origin |\
while read ref; do
    git grep '<artifactId>requestanalyzer' $ref -- **/pom.xml
done
```

Comment: This is good, but xargs complains: "unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option" when i use `xargs -0 -I {} git grep '<artifactId>requestanalyzer' {} -- **/pom.xml`

Comment: @caduceus: if using a `xargs` one liner becomes the issue, use a simpler method. I regularly write throwaway scripts so that I can bring `xargs` call down to : `... | xargs ./wip.sh`, you can also write a loop, or save the result in a file and write your command using that file, or ...

Comment: @ChatterOne : you are correct, I wrote the xargs sample because it is a straightforward way to say "use the output on the left in another command", but it is indeed a specific tool. Updated the answer with other options.

Comment: @LeGEC the loop is great `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads refs/remotes/origin | while read ref; do git grep -n '<artifactId>requestanalyzer' $ref -- **/pom.xml; done` Can you change your answer to remove xargs? It could be misleading.