# How to use git-grep to find all branches where "latest pom.xml" contains 'nexus.company.com'?

Tags: git

Question:

How to use git command line to find all branches where "latest pom.xml" contains the string 'nexus.company.com'?

**Context**

- we are switching our repo fqdn from 'nexus.company.com' to 'repo.company.com'
- company has *lots* of git repos
- we have access to the filesystem on the bitbucket server

**Requirement**

we want to:

- find all *latest* pom.xml which still refers to the old fqdn
- search on either *all* branches or a discrete list of standard branches (e.g "master", "development", and "release")

**Notes**

- I've tried using a combination of 'git grep', 'git rev-list' and piping it to git-show. Didn't quite work.
- pom.xml will likely be in root of the repo.
- A 'nice to have' would be to search ''all pom.xml' files in the repo
- We actually need to check build.gradle and other gulp/grunt build files.. I figured we can iterate on  'what works for pom.xml'

thanks!

Comment: You can use this small script https://github.com/da-x/git-search-replace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60390278/7976758